# Android "has already been added to output" error for jar in a project dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dependencies

I have an Android project that uses gradle with another project as dependency. Dependency project has a library jar. When I try to compile the project library is compiled twice and I get error:
    Error:Class no.nordicsemi.android.log.LogContract.Application has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

Here is the folder structure with files in question:

```
>ProjectRoot
  >dFULibrary
    >libs
      -nrf-logger-v2.0.jar
    -build.gradle
  >Logger
    -build.gradle
```

This is build.gradle for dFULibrary dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "no.nordicsemi.android.dfu"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar')
}
```

This is build.gradle for Logger (main project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src/main/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/main/res"
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project':dFULibrary')
}
```

no.nordicsemi.android.log.LogContract.Application class is found of nrf-logger-v2.0.jar Why is it being included twice and how can I make sure it does not?

**ADDITION**

Here is what ../gradlew dependencies return:

```
_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- project :dFULibrary

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :dFULibrary
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- project :dFULibrary

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :dFULibrary
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137 FAILED

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.1.201405082137 FAILED


compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
\--- project :dFULibrary


provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
```

I removed all the lines that had no dependencies.

**EDIT #2** output from  ./gradlew androidDependencies

```
:DFULibrary:androidDependencies
debug
\--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar

debugTest
+--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar
\--- debug
     \--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar

release
\--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar
:nRFToolbox:androidDependencies
debug
+--- LOCAL: achartengine-1.1.0.jar
\--- nrfToolbox:DFULibrary:unspecified
     \--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar

debugTest
No dependencies

release
+--- LOCAL: achartengine-1.1.0.jar
\--- nrfToolbox:DFULibrary:unspecified
     \--- LOCAL: nrf-logger-v2.0.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: If you use the `dependencies` Gradle task you can get some more insight into what's going on. You can run it from the command line from your main module's working directory (not the project root) via `../gradlew dependnecies`

Comment: Not sure, if it will help, but have you tried to change compile files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar') to provided files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar') (Normally it should not include this jar in output)

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately provided file() did not change anything. I updated the question with output of gradlew dependencies

Comment: Please provide also full output of `gradlew androidDependencies`

Comment: @gio added the output to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bingo, found it.

Just was interesting and I tried to find [your project](https://github.com/xuyuanme/ble-android) at Internet. And started my investigation .... :).

The problem is hidden at `nrf-logger-v2.0.jar`. It contains **.java** and **.class** files. 
Solution is to remove all **.java** files from it.

I did that Total Commander. Steps:

- rename `nrf-logger-v2.0.jar` into `nrf-logger-v2.0.zip`;
- go inside and remove all **.java** files;
- rename file back to **jar**;
- `gradlew clean build` or **Build-Rebuild project** at Android Studio
- voila

Comment: thanks a lot! I will be able to test this tomorrow and will respond here

Answer (score 0):

You should try to exclude the duplicate dependency as follows:

```
compile (project: ':dFULibrary'){
    exclude group: 'org.jacoco'
}
```

you should replace:

```
compile project':dFULibrary'
```

with the code from above.

Comment: Thank you. Tried that but still cannot run - same error.